# bootstrap-switch version 3.4.0 doesn't seem to change the checked property of the underlying INPUT

Tags: bootstrap-switch

I am using the latest version of bootstrap-switch.

I have the following HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" data-size="small" name="Scopes[0].AdviseListedEquities" checked>
```

I call `bootstrapSwitch()` on the element, which doesn't throw any errors.
However, the checkbox is in the off state, and when I check the checkbox, the underlying `checked` status doesn't change at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
3.4.0 is broken
Tried: 3.3.2, which works correctly.
```